# The given answer is 1,800, whereas I found it to be 1,600. Please explain how.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In an engineering college of 10,000 students, 1,500 like neither their core branches nor other branches. The number of students who like their core branches is 1/4th of the number of students who like other branches. The number of students who like both their core and other branches is 500.The number of students who like their core branches is

The method I used for solving:

Total students = 10,000

Students who like neither core nor other branches = 1,500

Students who like both core and other branches = 500

Let's denote:

Students who like only their core branches as x

Students who like only other branches as y

Given:

Total students $= x+y+500+1500 = 10,000$

We know that the number of students who like their core branches is 1/4th the number of students who like other branches, so $x = \frac{1}{4}y$

We can set up an equation using the information above and solve for x:

$\dfrac{1}{4} y + y + 500 + 1500 = 10,000$

We get y = 6,400​

Now, we can find x:

$x = \dfrac{1}{4} y = \dfrac{1}{4} \times 6400 = 1,600$

So, the number of students who like their core branches is 1,600.

Comment: I think it’s better to put a question, not an answer in the title.

Answer (score 4):

> $x = \dfrac{1}{4}y$

That's not correct. The question says -

> The number of students who like their core branches is 1/4th of the
> number of students who like other branches.

I don't see "only" used anywhere in the sentence. So,

$x + 500 = \dfrac{1}{4}(y + 500)$

This should give you the correct answer, $1800$.